# Del of spherical harmonics

Tags: spherical-harmonics

I am looking for the del of spherical harmonics.
For the laplace operator we have the defining relation: $\Delta Y^l_m = l(l+1) Y^l_m$.

So, what is with: $\nabla Y^l_m $

Comment: Do you know the definitions of $Y^l_m$ and $\nabla$? If you do, try applying the latter to the former, otherwise checking the definitions is the first thing to do.

Comment: Yes, but this is a bit of work and I thought there are some relations which I don't know yet. I was looking for something like eq.16 here: https://www.questaal.org/docs/numerics/spherical_harmonics/#gradients-of-spherical-harmonics

Comment: Doesn't this link answer your question?